# Add characters into BufferedReader

Tags: java, junit, junit4, nio

I would like to create mock test for reading file values into JUnit test.

I'm this code to read text code.

```
BufferedReader cpuReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/opt/test")));
```

In order to create JUnit test I need to add some dummy data which I need to keep into Java buffer. Just for example (it's completely wrong) I want to do this:

```
BufferedReader cpuReader = new BufferedReader():
cpuReader.addText("Some text");
// process further this data
```

Can you show me what is the correct way to add some text into the variable cpuReader when I initialize the Object BufferedReader()?

Comment: Use a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)?

Comment: Any example, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [PushbackReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html) to add text back into the stream:

```
String textToAdd = "Some text";
PushbackReader cpuReader = new PushbackReader(
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/opt/test"))),
    textToAdd.length());
cpuReader.unread(textToAdd.toCharArray());
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your idea. Any more information?

Comment: I think I misread what you wanted to do. I thought you wanted to prepend to the data read from the file. If you want to bypass the file entirely, use a StringReader as the other answers say.

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like this:

```
String str = "The string you want for your output";
BuffereReader r = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str))
```

Try not to mock files, there are many disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a BufferedReader based on a string

        String s = "This is my input\nIt has two lines\n";
        StringReader strReader = new StringReader(s);
        BufferedReader cpuReader = new BufferedReader(strReader);

        // Use the BufferedReader, regardless of its source.

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = cpuReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Note that once you have created the `cupReader`, you use it just like you did before, regardless of the fact that it's based on a `StringReader`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to hook up a BufferedReader with a PipedReader like this:

```
 PipedReader pipeR = new PipedReader();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(pipeR);
```

And then to connect the PipedReader with a PipedWriter like in:

```
  // create a new Piped writer and reader
  PipedWriter writer = new PipedWriter();

  // connect the reader and the writer
  pipeR.connect(writer);
```

Now (and in a dynamic fashion), whatever data you write using the writer write method, you can also read it via your BufferedReader